# How to perform test WHMCS Hook with some trigger URL?

Tags: whmcs

how can I test the whmcs hook 'invoicepaid' without paying the invoice each time to test the output of the $vars and function ?

```
<?php
add_hook('InvoicePaid', 1, function($vars) {
    // Perform hook code here...
});
```

Could it be something like that can trigger the invoicepaid hook ? e.g. ?id=43&hook=invoicepaid?

Comment: You cannot test hooks in any other way.

Comment: Create script that uses api functions CreateInvoice + AddInvoicePayment and run from command line.